# Styling the SharePoint List Column Filter Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, cssregistration, style.css

My users are filtering the column "State" from SharePoint list , Which consists of almost more then 50 values due to which users are getting a long list of choice to select as below.

Now i am thinking to apply some css or JavaScript and present the filter dialog options in 5 rows and 5 columns by increasing it's width .Can any help me in doing this.

[image]